# count multiple row values in the same query, mysql

Tags: mysql, count

table Devices:

```
id   device type_id device_status
1     dev1     2        1         
2     dev2     2        2        
3     dev3     7        2         
4     dev5     9        3
```

models table:

```
model_id vendor_id model_name
  1        3          name1          
  2        5          name2       
  3        7          name3         
  4        7          name4
```

and query looks this:

```
 SELECT model_id, type_id, model_name,
 COUNT(type_id) AS numOfDevices
 FROM devices
 LEFT JOIN models ON models.model_id = devices.type_id
 WHERE device_status = 2 OR device_status = 3
 GROUP BY type_id
```

what I am getting from that query is:

```
There are $numOfDevices $model_name items.
```

and this is OK, but is there a way to count devices only with device_status =3 in the same query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT model_id, type_id, model_name,
 SUM(CASE WHEN device_status=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS device2,
 SUM(CASE WHEN device_status=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS device3,
 SUM(CASE WHEN device_status IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS device2device3
 FROM devices
 LEFT JOIN models ON models.model_id = devices.type_id
 WHERE device_status = 2 OR device_status = 3
 GROUP BY type_id
```

Comment: `SUM(device_status=2) AS device2` don't make it hardier then it is :) The "boolean" returns either 0 or 1, so your CASE WHEN isn't required.

Comment: i am getting error: {"errorInfo":["42000",1064,"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM devices\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLEFT JOIN models ON models.model_id = devices.type_id\r' at line 4"]}. BTW I'm using PDO and 5.1.62 is the version of mysql

Comment: that's fixed error, but (i am sorry) result is not what I really need,   I need them bout together (dev3+dev2) + dev3  separatly...  i tried SUM(CASE WHEN device_status=2 AND device_status=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) but it doesn't work

Comment: OR is the right one: SUM(CASE WHEN device_status=2 OR device_status=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: @InTry : Updated then answer with a case for both dev3+dev2.

Comment: Thank you very much!
is it wrong like this?: SUM(CASE WHEN device_status=2 OR device_status=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :P. You can do it like that as well. I just think it is nicer with a `IN` clause. Less code